# Getting back the File transfer dialog

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus

Is there any way to get back the file transfer dialog?

Answer (score 0):

In brief: no. Changing so would require editing the source code of the Nautilus file manager.

Comment: @abu_bua Why does it not provide an answer to the question? I don't use Nautilus myself but I've read that it's pretty slimmed-down over the years in terms of features. This apparently seems to be a feature that was present earlier and has now been removed. If that's not the case, please post your own answer to show how this feature can be used or made available in Nautilus (in 18.04).